# How to connect to QNAP NAS from Ubuntu 16.04 TLS with SMB 3.0 encryption enabled?

Tags: sharing

Context: Enabled SMB Encryption which only allows SMB 3 clients to access the affected shares.

Issue: Cannot connect from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to share which is QNAP NAS, SMB 3 enabled, and encrypted.

Debugging: Since I am new to the whole Linux and NAS world, searching online has not helped.

I tried the following
Connect to share using windows 10x64 - pass
Connect to share using Ubuntu - fail

Used Wireshark to see how the negotiation is working.
Windows: Negotiate Protocol Response (source is windows vm, destination is NAS): "Security mode: 0x01, Signing enabled"

Ubuntu: Negotiate Protocol Response (source is ubuntu vm, destination is NAS):  "Security Mode: 0x03, Mode, Password"

OS: Ubuntu, Linux 4.4.0-124-generic x86_64

Reference:
https://www.qnap.com/en/how-to/tutorial/article/how-to-use-smb-3-0-in-qts-4-2

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue by following the instructions on [How to force SMB2 protocol in samba?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546743/how-to-force-smb2-protocol-in-samba)

However, to understand the issue, the article below helped.
https://richardkok.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/wireshark-determining-a-smb-and-ntlm-version-in-a-windows-environment/